# Logstash - Does Dissect’s mapping support multiple match?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, logstash-filter

As my log have multiple pattern I need to use multiple dissect pattern so that if one pattern fails to recognize the log other can capture. Following pseudo configuration works,

```
"message" => "pattern1"
```

Or

```
"message" => "pattern2"
```

But following configuration is not working,

```
"message" => ["pattern1", "pattern2"]
```

Does dissect support these kinds of match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `dissect` only supports one mapping for each field.

If your log has multiple patterns, you will need to use `grok`, which supports multiple matching patterns.

Depending on how are your log messages you can use a combination of conditionals to filter your messages and send each one to a matching `dissect`, or combine `grok` and `dissect` to parse common parts of your message.

You can also filter by the `_dissectfailure` tag, if your second pattern don't match the `dissect`, it will receive this tag and then you can apply a matching `dissect`

Comment: Hmm, but I saw something similar on the following post/answer, https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-dissect/issues/56#issuecomment-384229224

Comment: This link is an open issue asking for support for multiple patterns, the post you linked is just someone discussing how it could work if implemented, it is not how it works, currently dissect only supports one mapping per field.